# How do I create a link that sends the user to another page which is then diverted to another page associated with the link?

Tags: php, html

How do I create a link that sends the user to another page which is then diverted to another page associated with the link?

I would like to create a list of html URLS that as any one of them is clicked, it sends the user to an intermediary page, which asks the user whether they agree to the terms and conditions. If they do they are diverted to that page corresponding to that link they clicked. Similary to this diagram.
[image]

```
Link 1 ==> Intermediary Page ==> Page 1,
Link 2 ==> Intermediary Page ==> Page 2,
Link 3 ==> Intermediary Page ==> Page 3,
Link 4 ==> Intermediary Page ==> Page 4,
Link 5 ==> Intermediary Page ==> Page 5
```

I do not know what process it called. I intend to use HTML and PHP.

Comment: Dont not write I know I can google it. People here will hate that and will say you have not tried to find out for your self.

Comment: hint: make a list of those pages, give each one an ID, pass that ID in URL, retrieve it as a GET parameter on that intermediary page, then redirect to a real URL once form with terms is submitted and accepted

Answer (score 2):

First HTML page

```html
<a href="intermediary.php?q=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="intermediary.php?q=2">Link 2</a>
<a href="intermediary.php?q=3">Link 3</a>
<a href="intermediary.php?q=4">Link 4</a>
<a href="intermediary.php?q=5">Link 5</a>
```

intermediary.php

```php
<?php
$link = (int)$_GET["q"];
?>
<a href="page<?=$link?>.html">I agree to the terms and conditions</a>
```

Comment: How does that redirect the user to a target page?

Comment: @xFortyFourx Did you downvote it? You can't just do a redirect. Read the OP's post. He needs people to "agree to the terms and conditions". So click on that link and boom you're on the right page.

Comment: Sorry about that, negligence on my part :)

Comment: I would advise against using this approach. First you would need to handle all those non-semantic links. Second, what prohibits the user from going directly to page1.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can user GET variables in a URL. eg http://www.mysite.com/intermediary-page?page=page1

So this will link to the Intermediary page. Then on that page you will have a function that looks at the last part of the url `page=page1.` Then that function will then redirect the user to the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a href="inter.php?target=1">Some page</a>
<a href="inter.php?target=2">Some page</a>
<a href="inter.php?target=something_else">Some page</a>
```

PHP: inter.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$link='#';
switch($_GET['target']) {
 case 1:
       $link = "http://nexttarget.com";
       break;
 case 2:
       $link = "http://nexttarget2.com";
       break;
 case "something_else":
       $link = "http://nexttarget3.com";
       break;
}
$_SESSION['prev_link'] = "http://source_url";
?>

<form action="<?php echo $link; ?>" method="post">
<p>Your T&C here</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agreed" />
<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

PHP: target.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !isset($_POST['agreed']) || $_POST['agreed'] != 'agreed' ){
 header("Location: ".$_SESSION['prev_link']);
 exit;
}
?>
Your target page content here
```

EDIT: Edited to show T&C page instead of directly redirecting.

**EDIT 2**: *Now the intermediate page will redirect automatically upon agreeing/clicking the checkbox.*

PHP: inter.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$link='#';
switch($_GET['target']) {
  case 1:
    $link = "http://nexttarget.com";
    break;

  case 2:
    $link = "http://nexttarget2.com";
    break;

  case "something_else":
    $link = "http://nexttarget3.com";
    break;
}
$_SESSION['prev_link'] = "http://source_url";
?>

<form action="<?php echo $link; ?>" method="post" id="tc_form" >
  <p>Your T&amp;C here</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agreed" onclick="javascript: this.parentNode.submit();" id="check" />
  <label for="check">I agree to the T&amp;C.</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried the above but it isn't working for me. Any help please? Its not diverting to the target destination its remaining in inter.php

Comment: @PannyMonium Yes, it'll only print the link to the next page, what else is it that you want? You want to stay on the intermediate page for a few seconds and then automatically redirect?

Comment: I want that as the terms and conditions box is checked and the go button is clicked, it takes the user to the destination page based on the previous page.

Comment: Hi. I did it your way. Its redirecting now. Thanks. The problem that after it is redirected target.php in your example above. It is taking me to the URL - http://source_url which is found in inter.php. How do I prevent target.php from redirecting me to http://source_url found in inter.php?

Comment: @PannyMonium it's right there, `$_SESSION['prev_link'] = "http://source_url";`. Change that to whatever you want. Also, `target.php` is redirecting because the user hasn't agreed to T&C.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that's used a lot goes like this:

```
intermediary-page.php?proceedTo=some/url/to-go-next.php
```

On the intermediary-page.html (or php or whatever) page you perform the necessary verifications and redirect the  user to the url available in `proceedTo` GET variable.

After that, it depends on your requirements. Do you want security or ensure that the user has accepted the terms and conditions or whatever? Then you should perform additional verifications on each page like so:

> Link 1 -> Page 1 (check if the user has accepted the terms already? no? then:) ->
>   intermediary?proceedTo=page1 -> (ask the user to accept! accepted? then:) -> Page 1 (user
>   has accepted the terms now? yes? then:) -> stay here...

The advantages of this approach are:

1. You are pretty sure that even if a user has bypassed the intermediary page and went straight for the final destination - (s)he will get thrown back to the intermediary page (as if you were authenticating the user).
2. You don't need to create links like `href="intermediary.php?next=abc.php"`, instead just go with simple `href="abc.php"` which will handle redirection itself.

Comment: well, this is not very secure, given you're actually passing the redirect URL as a parameter, so terms accepting can be bypassed

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're passing the redirect URL as a parameter. If you care about security - then embed authentication/user validation inside every destination page. Worrying about URLs being visible relates to security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

First page:

```
<a href="intermediary.php?next_page=somepage.php">link to Intermediary Page</a>
```

Intermediary Page:

```
<?php

$next_page = $_REQUEST["next_page"];
header("Location: " . $next_page);

?>
```

Comment: well, this is not very secure, given you're actually passing the redirect URL as a parameter, so terms accepting can be bypassed

Comment: This is just a simple example, if you want to make it secure you can write some logic for that purpose...

Comment: He could just put 'somepage' in the url then the function turn it into 'somepage.php'

Comment: A lot of things can be done to make this better, again this is just a simple example...

Answer (score 0):

your HTML link:

```
<a href="/links.php?page=1">Link 1</a>
<a href="/links.php?page=2">Link 1</a>
```

your PHP code in `links.php`:

```
<?php

$page = !empty($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : null;

if (!empty($page)) {

    switch ($page) {

        case 1:
            header('Location: abc.php');
            break;

        case 2:
            header('Location: xyz.php');
            break;
    }
}
```

The other options is:

```
$pages[1] = 'abc.php';
$pages[2] = 'xyz.php';

header('Location: ' . $pages[$page]);
```

Note: Try to secure the `$page` variable, before using it.