# PHP code to user to another page which associated with the link

Tags: php

I am following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704556/how-do-i-create-a-link-that-sends-the-user-to-another-page-which-is-then-diverte) - it is to redirect a user a URL based on the link in the previous page.

and I am trying this solution:

HTML

```
<a href="inter.php?target=1">Some page</a>
<a href="inter.php?target=2">Some page</a>
<a href="inter.php?target=something_else">Some page</a>
```

inter.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$link='#';
switch($_GET['target']) {
  case 1:
    $link = "http://nexttarget.com";
    break;

  case 2:
    $link = "http://nexttarget2.com";
    break;

  case "something_else":
    $link = "http://nexttarget3.com";
    break;
}
$_SESSION['prev_link'] = "http://source_url";
?>

<form action="<?php echo $link; ?>" method="post" id="tc_form" >
  <p>Your T&amp;C here</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agreed" onclick="javascript: this.parentNode.submit();" id="check" />
  <label for="check">I agree to the T&amp;C.</label>
</form>
```

The above code works perfectly fine. Though I don't want my users to agree with the Terms and Conditions. I just want them to click the link and be diverted. When I remove the HTML code not to have the terms and conditions. This is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I know I can have a URL directly to that page but I would like it to be done through the inter.php please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send out a Location HTTP header to do a redirect from PHP:

```
<?php

$link='#';
switch($_GET['target']) {
  case 1:
    $link = "http://nexttarget.com";
    break;

  case 2:
    $link = "http://nexttarget2.com";
    break;

  case "something_else":
    $link = "http://nexttarget3.com";
    break;
}

header('Location: ' . $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting via Javascript on `click` of your checkbox element. By removing it you have no other way of submitting the form. Simply add this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```